# IndexError: string index out of range in RLE python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rle

if i input  **A9** output **AAAAAAAAA** but i input **A10** program will be error index out of range. how to fix the program when im input **A10** or above the program is workly.
This my code

```
Char = input ("Input Char : ")
Total = len(Char)
Decompress =""

for i in range (0, Total,2):
    Loop = int(Char[i+1])
    for j in range (0, Loop):
        Decompress = Decompress + Char [i]
        
print("Output : ",Decompress)
```

Comment: I would say that the problem is quite obvious - you're doing `int(Char[i+1])`. That will always be a single digit. Why is there even a loop if your input is a single letter and some numbers?

Comment: How to fix it but use the code based and plis dont use library

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop (or two loops!) here.

Simply multiply the string:

```
Char = input("Input Char : ")
print("Output : ", Char[0]*int(Char[1:]))
```

output:

```
Input Char : A15
Output :  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

##### more generic input

assuming you want to handle repeated pairs of char(s)/digits, this is quite easy to achieve with a regex:

```
import re

Char = input ("Input Char : ")
print("Output : ", ''.join(c*int(n) for c,n in re.findall('(\D+)(\d+)', Char)))
```

example:

```
Input Char : A2B10CD3
Output : AABBBBBBBBBBCDCDCD
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the loop is there to allow something like `A4B3` which will result `AAABBB` but of course the OP should clarify

Comment: @Tomerikoo could be but in this case OP's code is far from being able to do that as you would need to identify the letters/numbers

Comment: OP's code works with single digits (try my input above). That's why the loop is there, it loops in a step of two so always looking at the current letter and the following digit. This is why I believe the crux of the question is how to broaden it to allow multiple digits to which the easiest solution is most likely regex (or maybe `groupby`...)

Comment: there is no other way but to use the library